# Dynamically generating a option list ends up with repeated optgroup tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, algorithm, html-select

I know there must be a simple answer to this: I am trying to dynamically populate a select box. I have been successful to an extent but when i put an  to the options it keeps repeating itself with every option Please check my code and tell me what in an doing wrong

```
$country_id = 'management';
$country_id = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST["country_id"]));
<!--db details-->
$dbc2 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST2, DB_USER2, DB_PASSWORD2, DB_NAME2) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$q = "SELECT b.institute_state, b.institute_district, b.institute_location 
FROM institutes_courses a, institutes b
WHERE a.institute_course_stream = '".$country_id."'
AND a.institute_id = b.institute_id
group by b.institute_district
ORDER BY institute_state ASC
";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc2, $q);
$institutes = array();

while(list($institute_state, $institute_district, $institute_location) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $institutes[] = array('state' => $institute_state, 'district' => $institute_district, 'location' => $institute_location);
}//end while

echo  '<select name="state" id="drop2" required>
<option value="" id="state" selected>Please Select A Location</option>';

foreach ($institutes as $inst) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$inst['state'].'">';
    //echo '<optgroup label="'.$inst['state'].'">';


        echo '<option value="'.$inst['location'].'">State: '.$inst['state'].', Location: '.$inst['location'].'</option>';

        echo '</optgroup>';
    }

echo '</select>';
```

This gives me a result like so:

```html
<optgroup label:state>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label:state>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label:state2>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label:state2>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>etc...
```

I want it to be like this:

```html
<optgroup label:state>
  <option>District</option>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label:state2>
  <option>District</option>
  <option>District</option>
</optgroup>etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify if your `$inst['state']` change, in this case I add a control var named `$count`, change your code to this:

```
<?php

$institutes = array();
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'delhi', 'location' => 'mg road');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'delhi', 'location' => 'delhi_loc');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'karnataka', 'location' => 'kannur_ayikere');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state1', 'location' => 'location1');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state1', 'location' => 'location2');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state1', 'location' => 'location3');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state2', 'location' => 'location1');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state3', 'location' => 'location1');
$institutes[] = array('state' => 'state3', 'location' => 'location2');

echo  '<select name="state" id="drop2" required>
<option value="" id="state" selected>Please Select A Location</option>';

$label = '';
$cant = array_count_values(array_column($institutes, 'state'));
$count = 0;

foreach ($institutes as $inst) {

    if($count == 0) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$inst['state'].'">';
    }
        echo '<option value="'.$inst['location'].'">State: '.$inst['state'].', Location: '.$inst['location'].'</option>';
        $count++;

    if($cant[$inst['state']] == $count) {
        echo '</optgroup>';
        $count = 0;
    }

    $label =  $inst['state'];
  }

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: thanks adrian, your answer was very helpful. but now a small issue with `</optgroup>` tag: 
`<select name="state" id="drop2" required>
 <option value="" id="state" selected>Please Select A Location</option>
    <optgroup label="delhi">
    <option value="mg road">State: delhi, Location: mg road</option>
    </optgroup><!-- this comes below-->
    <option value="delhi_loc">State: delhi, Location: delhi_loc</option>
    <optgroup label="karnataka">
    <option value="kannur_ayikere">State: karnataka, Location: kannur_ayikere</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>`

Comment: @Exsite can you give a clue, I can't see the problem

Comment: The `</optgroup>` ends immediately after the first `<option>` and continues until the other state is got. `<select name="state" id="drop2" required><option value="" id="state" selected>Please Select A Location</option>
<optgroup label="delhi"><option value="mg road">State: delhi, Location: mg road</option></optgroup>` this optgroup (end) should be below
 `<option value="delhi_loc">State: delhi, Location: delhi_loc</option>` optgroup (end) is required `<optgroup label="karnataka"><option value="kannur_ayikere">State: karnataka, Location: kannur_ayikere</option></optgroup></select>`. Thx 4 help

Comment: hope my explanation was understandable. Really appreciate your help. Am not familiar with how to format the comments with code

Comment: @Exsite I edit my answer and I add an example, now it works as expected.